# Copy/pasting feature in codeblocks in linux

Tags: linux, ide, codeblocks, copy-paste, linux-mint

I have installed Code::Blocks 12.11 in my linux mint but pasting input at runtime in the command line(I think it is called command line)doesn't seem to work.I have to type the whole input inorder to get output.Can anybody tell me how to fix this?

P.S :- I have tied ctrl+V as well as right click and paste but nothing really working in my case

Answer (score 6):

This problem arises when you have **xterm** as your launch terminal.You can solve this by switching your terminal from **xterm** to **gnome-terminal**.

```
 Go to Settings -> Environment -> Terminal to Launch Console Programs
```

and change the launch terminal from xterm to gnome terminal from the options.

Answer (score 3):

In the terminal, for ***copy*** and ***paste***:

```
Shift+Ctrl-c and Shift+Ctrl-v
```

In the Xterm, for ***pasting***:

```
Middle click or Shift-Insert
```

if you want to ***copy*** in the xterm, you just **select the text with your mouse** and paste using the middle click or Shift-Instert, but it just works inside the xterm.